# JavaScript to parse a soap request

Tags: javascript

Hi i wanto to Parse the following XML file, as you can see its a webService request:

```
importPackage(Packages.java.io);
importPackage(Packages.java.lang);
importPackage(Packages.java.util);
importPackage(Packages.org.w3c.dom);
importPackage(Packages.com.vordel.circuit);
importPackage(Packages.com.vordel.common.base64);
importPackage(Packages.com.vordel.dwe);
importPackage(Packages.com.vordel.mime);
importPackage(Packages.com.vordel.trace);
importPackage(Packages.com.vordel.common.util);
importPackage(Packages.com.vordel.es);
importPackage(Packages.com.vordel.es.xes);

function invoke(msg)         {
var Container = msg.get ("container");
var Policy= msg.get ("Policy_AccountActivity");
    try {
var espk = PortableESPKFactory.newInstance().createPortableESPK(
    "<key type='CircuitContainer'>" + 
        "<id field='name' value='"+Container+"'/>" + 
        "<key type='FilterCircuit'>" +
            "<id field='name' value='"+Policy+"'/>" + 
        "</key>" + 
    "</key>");
// Here obtaining a reference on the Policy to be invoked
var circuit = Service.getInstance().getLocalPack().cache.getCircuit(espk);
// Setting up a dummy context, needed to invoke the Policy afterwards
var context = new java.lang.String("DefaultContext");
        // get the xml body
        var body = XMLBody.locate(msg);
        var doc = body.getDocument();
        var root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        var NameElement = "get_Account_Activity_Request";

        var nodes = 
            root.getElementsByTagName(NameElement);

        if ((nodes == null) || (nodes.getLength() <= 0)) {
           Trace.error("There were no "+NameElement+" elements found in the message");
           return false;
        }
        var content = new StringBuffer();
        var compteur =  1;


        for (i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            var toProcess = nodes.item(i);

            if (toProcess == null)
               continue;

            // get the contents of the element
            var children = toProcess.getChildNodes();
            Trace.debug("Getting children");
             msg.put("MessageIDCTP",compteur.toString());
           compteur+=1;

             for (j = 0; j < children.getLength(); j++) {

                 var node = children.item(j);
                if (node.getNodeName() == "mob:maxNbRecord") {
                        var childrenMaxNbRecord= node.getChildNodes();
                        var nodeMaxNbRecord= childrenMaxNbRecord.item(0);
                        var value= nodeMaxNbRecord.getNodeValue();
                msg.put ("account.MaxNbRecord" , value.toString() ) ; 
                   }
                    if (node.getNodeName() == "mob:startDate") {
                        var childrenStartDate= node.getChildNodes();
                        var nodeStartDate= childrenStartDate.item(0);
                        var value= nodeStartDate.getNodeValue();

                msg.put ("account.StartDate" , value.toString() ) ; 

                   }

                    if (node.getNodeName() == "mob:endDate") {
                        var childrenEndDate= node.getChildNodes();
                        var nodeEndDate= childrenEndDate.item(0);
                        var value= nodeEndDate.getNodeValue();

                msg.put ("account.EndDate" , value.toString() ) ;               
                }

                if (node.getNodeName() == "mob:minAmount") {
                        var childrenMinAmount= node.getChildNodes();
                        var nodeMinAmount= childrenMinAmount.item(0);
                        var value= nodeMinAmount.getNodeValue();

                msg.put ("account.MinAmount" , value.toString() ) ;                     
                }   
                        if (node.getNodeName() == "mob:maxAmount") {
                        var childrenMaxAmount= node.getChildNodes();
                        var nodeMaxAmount= childrenMaxAmount.item(0);
                        var value= nodeMaxAmount.getNodeValue();

                msg.put ("account.MaxAmount" , value.toString() ) ; 

                InvocationEngine.invokeCircuit(circuit, context, msg);
                }
            }
      }
 }

catch (exp) {
        Trace.error(exp);
    }
    return true;
}



     <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org           /soap/envelope/" xmlns:acc="URL" xmlns:mob="URL">
      <soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
         <acc:get_Account_Activity_RequestFlow>
        <mob:requestHeader>
        <mob:requestId>1</mob:requestId>
        <mob:serviceName>WS_WebserviceName</mob:serviceName>
        <mob:timestamp>2015-04-22T18:12:06.84585</mob:timestamp>
        </mob:requestHeader>
        <acc:get_Account_Activity_Request>
        <mob:accountID>
           <mob:Code1>0003</mob:Code1>
           <mob:Code2>552</mob:Code2>
           <mob:Code3>056897</mob:Code3>
        </mob:accountID>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <mob:maxNbRecord>1</mob:maxNbRecord>
        <mob:startDate>2015-04-22T18:12:06.00000</mob:startDate>
        <mob:endDate>2015-04-22T19:12:06.00000</mob:endDate>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <mob:minAmount>0000.0000</mob:minAmount>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <mob:maxAmount>6000.0000</mob:maxAmount>
         </acc:get_Account_Activity_Request>
      </acc:get_Account_Activity_RequestFlow>
      </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>
```

My script is gathering the following elements that come in an immediate level under acc:get_Account_Activity_Request.

But my issue is that i dont know how to retrieve the elements code1, 2 and 3 that come inside the  tag:

When i do an "if (node.getNodeName() == "mob:Code1")" this element is not found.

Any advise would be hugely appreciated